# Fireworks batch renaming doesn't work (remove '.fw')

Tags: batch-processing, adobe-fireworks

I'm handling a lot of company images (300+) at various resolutions (16, 48, 256) and the appended '.fw' is becoming a huge waste of time for me.

After creating the images at the 3 resolutions I use the extremely useful batch process built-in to Adobe Fireworks. However, while the exporting function works fine, the renaming one doesn't. I ask it to replace '.fw.png' with .png' but it doesn't work.

Any idea why? and if there's a fix?
I have a suspicion that it's because it part of the file extension.

The image below shows the fields available to specify the batch. The 'With' field doesn't allow any '.' (periods, full-stops).

[image: screenshot of Fireworks batch process]

Comment: What about Bridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are third-party renaming applications that will do a better job; Fireworks won't help here probably.

Maybe you can try http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilerenamer/ ? :-)

[EDIT] I have just tested Free File Renamer (see link above). It worked fine! :)

- open the app;
- click on "select folder" and browse to the folder with the *.fw.png files;
- select all;
- go to "add operation" tab;
- click "replace" and use "find what: .fw.png/replace with: .png", make sure also to check "include extension" checkbox, then click on "add" button;
- then click "home" tab again, click "rename" button, done! :-)

Comment: The download seemed to be a bit dodgy for that but i found another one http://www.advancedrenamer.com/download

Comment: Also thanks for the answer Michel. The app I found worked perfectly. The only problem with the link you sent was the font file within the program was only rendering certain characters. Weird

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution! :-) (Not sure why the other app didn't work, though... it was OK on my end. I tested it on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'General' tab and remove the hook from the check-box.

[image]